# checking if values from list in MySQL column Python

Tags: python, sql

I'm new to SQL (MySQL) and I was wondering if I can do following using Python: 
I have a list in python with some numbers and I have a column which contains numbers in MySQL, so I need to check if the number from the Python list exists in a column of Data base. 
If yes return True, if no return False.

```
import  pyodbc as SQL 

con = SQL.connect('Driver = {MySQL}; Server=localhost; 
Database=Items)

items =['11','12', '13', '14']
for i in items:
cur.execute("select * from ItemNumber", (items[i]))
item = cur.fetchall()
if not item:
   return False   
else:
   return True
```

Comment: Where is you code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: "I was wondering if I can do following using python" If that's your question, then the answer is yes you can. If you want a more precise/complete answer ask a precise/complete following [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide

Comment: Sorry, you can see the code in the question field now. @ vincrichaud, @D-Shih

Comment: @DerekBrown thank you so mujch!

Comment: Your SQL isn't using the parameter you're passing. Do you mean e.g. `select * from ItemNumber where id = ?`

Comment: @Rup do I have to change it like this:   **select * from Items where ItemNumber ?**

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this below:

```
import pandas as pd

items =['11','12', '13', '14']
df_items = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['ID'])

sql = "select * from ItemNumber"
df_db = pd.read_sql_query(sql, con)
df_db.ID = df_db.ID.astype(str)

df_final = df_items.merge(df_db,on='ID',how='left')

print(df_final)
```

Comment: wouldn't it just add the list to the column? and I just need to know, if the item exists in data base...

Comment: it was a `SELECT` statement you originally had: Select in SQL *extracts a data set* from the database. Now you had the data set in memory in Python and decide what to do..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. So now I have a data set from MySQL in Python memory and can compare it? Is it possible to compare the items without extraction to Python? this is too big...

Comment: what do you want to do actually? The code I sent; filters that DB table ItemNumber in the DB. You want to pull the entire table instead and filter/compare it by your list in Python? That is possible too.  It is software, anything is possible :)

Comment: I have a list of items in python, I want to check if any of this items exists in column of a data base (it could be one item, two items all of items from or none from the list). So my idea was: connect to db, iterate throught the list, and compare every item from the column to the item from the list, if I have a match, return the match or True...but it seems not to working...

Comment: I have edited my answer. As said there are many ways to do it but I tried the following : I just converted the sql answer of db table and the items list as well to dataframe . Then I performed a **sql left join** between the items list and the db table. At `df_final` dataframe you now see which of the items in the list are in the db table.